# What does 「連中の宣伝にならんだろ」mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrases

From Persona 5

> テレビ観ました? 会社がハッカーに狙われるかも
>
> ウチみたいな零細、相手にするかよ。 連中の宣伝にならんだろ。

What does 「連中の宣伝にならんだろ」mean in this sentence? At first I guessed that it means "it's not good publicity (宣伝)　for them (連中)," but I'm not actually sure. Having trouble understanding 「宣伝にならない」　as a phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. 宣伝になる means "to serve as advertising". This person is saying that hacking his company wouldn't be a way for a hacker to gain publicity. While hackers often target organizations for financial gain or ideological reasons, they sometimes do so simply out of a desire for fame. This person says that because his company is small, it's unlikely to be a target for hackers seeking fame. (He does not seem to be considering the possibility that his company is targeted for financial reasons.)